# how can i pass value from javascript to my php function codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php

Thank for help and attention.I'm apprentice

I tried this already

if i did it wrong way your can tell me anything.i learning. thanks.

checkfb() is a php function and outside script i want to call checkfb() in script function with pass javascript value.if in php looklike simply pass by value checkfb($fbFName,$fbLName,$Email); ?> but cant do cuz in script scope.i am sorry if i made your misunderstanding.

```
function checkLoginState() {
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  statusChangeCallback(response);
                    <?php $this->checkfb($fbFName,$fbLName,$Email); ?>
              });

public function checkfb($FName,$LName,$Email){

    print_r('checkfb') ; exit();
  }
  //code work for log in facebook already but i wanna add data into my database      

function getCurrentUserInfo() {
<script>
              FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,picture', function(userInfo) {

                  fbFName = userInfo.first_name;
                  fbLName = userInfo.last_name;
                  fbEmail = userInfo.email;
                  fbLink = userInfo.link;
                  fbGender = userInfo.gender;
                  fbpicture = userInfo.picture;
                  alert(fbID);
                  console.log(fbID);
                  console.log(fbFName);
                  console.log(fbLName);
                  console.log(fbEmail);

              });
          }
          function checkLoginState() {
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                  statusChangeCallback(response);
              });
          }
      </script>
```

Comment: to pass value from js u use ajax to send that value to php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ajax to pass the value in PHP, That is the best way.

Comment: thanks but this is not my meaning.checkfb() is a php function and outside script i want to call checkfb() in script function with pass javascript value.if in php looklike simply pass by value <?php $this->checkfb($fbFName,$fbLName,$Email); ?> but cant do cuz in script scope.i am sorry if i made your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the JS function, use the php variables as parameters. Change

```
function checkLoginState() {
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  statusChangeCallback(response);
                    <?php $this->checkfb($fbFName,$fbLName,$Email); ?>
              });
```

to

```
function checkLoginState() {
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  statusChangeCallback(response);
                   checkfb('<?php=$fbFName?>','<?php=$fbLName?>','<?php=$Email?>'); ?>
              });
```

Comment: thanks but this is not my meaning.checkfb() is a php function and outside script i want to call checkfb() in script function with pass javascript value.if in php looklike simply pass by value <?php $this->checkfb($fbFName,$fbLName,$Email); ?> but cant do cuz in script scope.i am sorry if i made your misunderstanding.

Comment: you need ajax here, you need server side processing, write the code on server side and have  an ajax call

Comment: Thanks.I Solved my problem.I write this script in controller that why i got a problem i just move to view and use ajax to send value to controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at Ajax.

In Javascript Code:

```
function myJsCallback(myJsVar) {
  $.get("http://example.com/api/fb/checkfb?myJsVar=" + myJsVar,
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
}
```

In PHP

```
public function myRouteHandler() {
    $myJsVar = $_GET['myJsVar'];
    // check whatever here
}
```

Comment: thanks but this is not my meaning.checkfb() is a php function and outside script i want to call checkfb() in script function with pass javascript value.if in php looklike simply pass by value <?php $this->checkfb($fbFName,$fbLName,$Email); ?> but cant do cuz in script scope.i am sorry if i made your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.I Solved my problem.I write this script in controller that why i got a problem i just move to view and use ajax to send value to controller. :)